# New Customer address attribute not saving on Frontend

Tags: customer-attribute, customer-address, address-attribute

I have created a new customer address attribute, it shows the field correctly on the frontend BUT it doesn't allow you to save the data.

It does work correctly when saving through admin, and then does appear on the frontend after a cache flush.

Comment: what code you used to save value? pls share the code what you used.

Comment: The customer address attribute was created through admin, it appears correctly on the customer address form on the frontend and also the admin side.

I have local and staging environments and it works correctly on both of those.

But for production environment, it works correctly in admin, when adding a new address and filling the field out it saves correctly and can view that on the frontend.

But when then trying to do the same on the frontend it does not save correctly.

Comment: hi @Rodders, there is no option available in admin to create customer address in CE version of magento, how the address attribute created? any extension is used?

Comment: Created through, Stores -> Customer Address Attributes //

Add new attribute

Comment: may be you have installed some extension, that feature not available in default magento2

Comment: I am using Magento EE ver. 2.2.3

Comment: sorry No idea about EE edition, let me check